# Cual es la mejor forma de generar el archivo APK de un proyecto en polymer V1.0

Tags: android, cordova, aplicación-web, polymer

Estoy buscando la forma de generar un .apk desde un proyecto de polymer.

Estoy trabajando con la versión 1.0  específicamente del PSK generado con yeoman: `yo polymer`. He tratado con cordova y también con el proyecto generado con yeoman: `yo polymer-cordova` y al generar el archivo .apk me muestra el mismo error: una pantalla blanca sin información ni nada.

Actualmente no le he hecho ningún cambio al paquete PSK pero no he podido solucionar este problema, lo he probado en un Galaxy Note 1 android 4.0.4 y en genymotion android 4.1.0 y me muestra el mismo problema.

Comment: Hola @gustavosm, bienvenido a SOes para poderte ayudar es necesario que muestres alguna información adicional sobre el problema que se te presenta. Quizas usando https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging puedas mirar cual es el error y postearlo aqí.

Comment: Podrias postear que error te arroja si lanzas la aplicacion y ejecutas DDMS, la otra es que obtengas los errores con las herramientas del Chrome ( https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging ). Lo otro podria ser que la webview de cordova no soporta bien Polymer, entonces podrias intentar instalando Crosswalk.